# The meaning of the word "decanter"?

Tags: meaning, verbs, vocabulary

I have looked up the word **decanter** in several dictionaries to find a meaning that matches its use in the sentence below, but I failed.

> In a problem-based learning setting, teachers need to **decanter** their roles as the source of knowledge by consciously refraining from giving only right-wrong answers.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I think this is a typo for the "decenter", a word which has recently become very chic in academic circles.

Comment: I can think of several teachers who would rather be decanting than decentering!

Comment: `decentre` for those of us across the pond :o)

Comment: Yes, at least one version of this passage uses **decenter**, which indicates that "decanter" isn't the intended word: "http://www.edpsycinteractive.org/files/prbsollrn.html

Comment: Or *more decent,* @ne1410s, for those of us who prefer the compound comparative ;).

Comment: @BrianDonovan =D Très drôle

Comment: @WS2  Indeed; there are many teachers whose roles include dregs they would just as soon discard.

Comment: @StoneyB you should go ahead and submit this as an answer, not just a comment.  Clearly it is the answer to what the intent of the original passage was.  The way "decenter" is used here feels awkward to me, but I won't make any rewording attempts here.

Comment: @Developer63 As you wish.

Comment: Yes, it seems like "decanting" is exactly what they want to avoid -- the "pouring" of "knowledge" into kids' brains without accompanying comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

I take this to be a typo for *decenter*—that is, for the loathsome but (alas) grammatical verb = "de-center", not the ungrammatical but at least tolerable comparative adjective, "decent-er".

I post this as a community wiki to encourage further explanation by anyone who both understands this faddish use and is not nauseated by it.

Comment: I do find decenter faddish, even awkward as used, but thankfully not quite nausea-inducing. Nice work on figuring out it was a typo/spell check word substitution issue!